# SQLite WITH + UNION issue

Tags: sqlite, union

my UNION queries cannot work when tables created by WITH are used, is this a SQLite limitation? for example -

This works:

```
with
T_one as (
    select * from T
),
T_two as (
    select * from T
)
select * from T_one
```

This does not work:

```
--union cannot see tables made by with
with
T_one as (
    select * from T
),
T_two as (
    select * from T
)
select * from T_one union select * from T_two
```

> (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: T_one [SQL: u'--union cannot see tables made by with\nwith\nT_one as (\n    select * from T\n),\nT_two as (\n    select * from T\n)\nselect * from T_one union select * from T_two']

Comment: Which version of SQLite are you using? The latter query seems to work happily on SQLite 3.8.5 (via sql.js on sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: I am running the query inside python 2.7.10, which comes with sqlite 3.8.3.1.  It turns out that if I run this directly with the sqlite 3.8.10.2 that comes with OSX, it works fine.

Comment: So now my question would be: how to upgrade my python sqlite to 3.8.10 ?

Comment: I upgraded to the current version of sqlite (http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/PySqlite) and it works now

Comment: Note: I'm on OSX El Capitain, and using a separate python installation (not the built in apple one) downloaded from python.org, and my .bash_profile is set up to point to this python installation
 
To upgrade my python sqlite to 3.9.1 I did this (per http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/PySqlite):
 
Downloaded pysqlite-2.8.1.tar.gz from trac.edgewall.org/wiki/PySqlite 
Downloaded sqlite-amalgamation-3090100.zip from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html
Unzipped both and put them in the same folder
Ran this command from the folder

Comment: Please add your own answer instead of suggesting an edit to the existing accepted answer. You can change the accepted answer as well, if you wish, once the 48 hour waiting period has elapsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running the query inside python 2.7.10, which comes with sqlite 3.8.3.1. It turns out that if I run this directly with the sqlite 3.8.10.2 that comes with OSX, it works fine.

I upgraded my python sqlite to 3.9.1 and it works now.

Instructions per trac.edgewall.org/wiki/PySqlite

1. Download pysqlite-2.8.1.tar.gz from
   trac.edgewall.org/wiki/PySqlite
2. Download sqlite-amalgamation-3090100.zip from
   sqlite.org/download.html
3. Unzip both and put them in the same folder
4. Run this command from the folder:

   python setup.py build_static install

Note: I'm using OSX El Capitain, and a separate python installation (not the built in apple one) downloaded from python.org, and my .bash_profile is set up to point to this python installation